# Where does the OS take the value for $OSTYPE

Tags: bash, jenkins, os-detection

I have a legacy script that depends on the value of `$OSTYPE` variable. What this script expects is that on Solaris the value is "SunOS" while on AIX it is "AIX". For Linux it checks the variable against the regex where the uppercased value starts with "LINUX".

I've tried to run this script from Jenkins, and discovered that the values are different: Solaris returns "solaris2.11" while AIX returns "aix7.1.0.0". I ran the `echo $OSTYPE` command on exactly the same servers where Jenkins runs the script, and I get "SunOS"/"AIX" instead.

So the main question I have is: what is the source of this difference (how does the system form the value of this variable, and why does Jenkins have different values than just echo ran from bash). A side question is which is the reliable way to use `$OSTYPE`.

Comment: This variable is set by Bash. Not in a place where I can examine its history to see whether this was changed and when.

Comment: @tripleee I tried to run the `echo $OSTYPE` from bash, sh, other shells available on the Solaris server: everything echoes "SunOS". The Groovy in Solaris uses an `sh` command (is it an 'sh' shell invocation?) I'm curious where does Jenkins take those values from.

Comment: Update: **zsh** returned "solaris2.11" but still returns "aix" on AIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `OSTYPE` stores the value of OS TYPE in the shell variables. It depends on shell what value it stores.

For example, if you are using `bash`, you will get one value of `OSTYPE` variable, in `zsh`, some other value and in `sh`, you may not get any value itself.

See the difference below in using `bash` and `zsh`.

**bash**

```
$ echo $OSTYPE
  darwin18
```

**zsh**

```
% echo $OSTYPE
  darwin18.0
```

So, you may need to check what shell `jenkins` is using when you are getting different values of `OSTYPE`

Comment: That partially answers my question. The echo from **zsh** indeed returned "solaris2.11" on Solaris, however this doesn't explain the issue on AIX: it still returns "aix" being run manually from zsh. Anyway thank you, I'm trying to identify which shell does Jenkins use on AIX.

Comment: I don't have access to any AIX machine to check further.

Comment: It would be very weird indeed if Jenkins used zsh, seeing as it has some syntactic differences from POSIX.

Answer (score 6):

The most reliable way is to use the command:

```
uname
```

with different options. The result you see is only the command `uname`. If you want more detailed info about version, architecture you can use

```
uname -a
```

Comment: Neither of these return the same string as `echo $OSTYPE`.  (macOS 12.0.1, Zsh 5.8)